# youtube v3 api : get all live streaming playlist ids of a channel

Tags: youtube, youtube-livestreaming-api

I have two "**Live streaming/live broadcast saved playlists**" in following youtube channel --> https://www.youtube.com/user/swaminarayanlive.

I am trying to retrieve all the "**live streaming / live broadcast playlists**" of a channel using **new youtube v3 api** by using the below link-->

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlists?part=snippet&channelId=UCBkNpeyvBO2TdPGVC_PsPUA&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

here i can get the info of playlists which are not live streams or live broadcast. and not able to get the same for the live one.

Please help me how can i get that for live one using **youtube v3 api**

Answer (score 1):

I was researching another issue with the API when finding this, and when I saw that this was never resolved, I decided to look into it. It turns out that this is related to that other issue.

The YouTube API v3 lacks support for saved playlists. The channel swaminarayanlive did not create the playlists, only saved them from the channel BhujMandir.

The workaround in your case would be to retrieve the playlists of BhujMandir and extract the response snippets with "title" parameters containing the word "Live".

You would need to go through the pages and search each one for this, since there is a limit to how many results an API response can show at once. Currently it's 50.

So, you would use the following to get the first page of playlistItems:

GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlists?part=snippet&channelId=UCVItNtUctAknegvmYcMhUQg&maxResults=50&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

This will return an API response containing the properties "kind" (which will have the value "youtube#playlistListResponse") and "etag". If there are more than 50 results, there will also be a "nextPageToken" property. (On a page that is not the first, there would also be a "prevPageToken" property.)

After these properties, there are two blocks. One called "pageInfo", containing info about how many results (playlists) there are and how many are shown per page, and one block called "items", containing the resulting playlistItems.

You would look through the items block for any playlistItem with a title property (which is a string) containing the substring "Live" and get the id properties of those. You would then look on the next page by using the nextPageToken's value in a new HTTP request, like so:

GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlists?part=snippet&channelId=UCVItNtUctAknegvmYcMhUQg&maxResults=50&pageToken=[nextPageToken_value_here]&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

As of now, the two playlists you're looking for are on the pages with tokens CJYBEAA and CMgBEAA.

Comment: good idea, but this solution will only work till the title of the playlist will contain the sub string "Live"

Comment: Haha, I just realized you can just create the playlists from the swaminarayanlive account xD

So the easy fix is to create two new playlists, open the old playlists and add each video to the new ones. Those playlists should be there when you make the http request you used before.

Answer (score -3):

I think that where is  the {YOUR_API_KEY} you should change this code and insert the name of your application program interface

Comment: For security purpose i did not include the API Key here in the question.. above link is working fine for uploads. but question is about live videos

Comment: I think probably that first for do a printer that have incorporate a scanner  that copy and paste everyone that you want you should learn and understand the code that you have paste because for me is a function that have three string errors , code and message

Comment: what is this mata gata stream ?

Comment: have a look at this youtube channel -->> https://www.youtube.com/user/swaminarayanlive. you'll find two saved playlists which are serving live videos. I want to list the ids of those two playlists using v3 api. which was earlier possible with v2 api

Comment: I dont know how to help you because i nothing have work with this API.

Comment: But i suggest you to view this link: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/?hl=en

Comment: Probably can help you